# Is taking square root of both parts of equation in this way is an equivalent transformation of the equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, radicals

Solve equation

$$(2x+7)^2=(2x-1)^2$$

$t=2x-1 $, so equation becomes $$ (t+8)^2 = t^2  $$

Now *let's make a "prohibited" - take a square root from both parts* (minding that $\sqrt{x^2} = \lvert x\rvert$), so we get a union of solutions of two equations

$$
t+8 = t \\ 
t+8 = - t
$$

$-(t+8) = t, -(t+8) = -t $ are same as the 2 equations above, so no need to solve them separately.

The first equation is a contradiction ( 0 = 8) so it has no solutions.

The second equation give $t = -4 \Rightarrow 2x-1 = -4 \Rightarrow x = -3/2$ and this is the only solution of the original quadratic equation, and it need not to be checked (substituted into original equation) because all transformations all along the way were equivalent.

May I go ahead and take square roots in that manner at my exams, is it OK?

Comment: Yes it is okay.

Comment: Looks ok. If you can do it in the exam is up to your teacher/professor, so maybe ask there. It might not only depend on whether it is right or not, but also how much you have to explain in the exam.

Comment: Another way would be to factor : $$(t+8)^2-t^2=(t+8-t)(t+8+t)=0$$ and use  that a product is $0$ if and only if one the factors is which exactly leads to your approach. In this case, however, multiplying the expressions out is also easy enough. In short, the approach is perfectly valid, but a bit unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any real number $a$ and $b$, $a^2=b^2$ *if and only if* $|a|=|b|$. So, a real number $x_0$ is a solution to the equation
$$
(2x+7)^2=(2x-1)^2,\tag{1}
$$
if and only if $x_0$ is a solution to the equation
$$
|2x+7|=|2x-1|.\tag{2}
$$

Equation (1) and Equat. (2) are equivalent. So what you did is OK.

---

One does not necessarily introduce the variable $t$ though: Equat. (2) implies that
$$
2x+7=2x-1\quad \textbf{or}\quad 2x+7=-(2x-1).
$$
Since $2x+7=2x-1$ is impossible, one has $2x+7=-(2x-1)$ and thus
$$
x=\frac{-7+1}{2}=-\frac32.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when the square root is taken from both sides, the equation results in two equivalent equations.

In fact, that is how the quadratic formula is obtained:
$$ax^2+bx+c=0 \iff \\
x^2+\frac bax+\frac ca=0\iff \\
\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}+\frac ca=0 \iff \\
\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2} \iff \\
x+\frac b{2a}= \frac{\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \iff \\
x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$

Comment: Your answer is also excellent!  It's a pity it cannot be added to the selected answer as a useful additional example. It's just my subjective personal preference - for me it is more clear with modulus.

Comment: I am glad that it was useful and upvoted. That is enough for me. It is also good to look at problems from different perspectives. Good luck.